# How to send a char through Bluetooth connection in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c++, c, windows-phone-8.1, arduino-uno

Last year i did one project with Android and Arduino. Where I could send some characters android from arduino.

Now i want to know how can i do in Windows Phone 8.1?

I found a lot of stuffs about it, but not what i really want, I just wish to create a simple button and send a message to my Arduino!

heres my code from C++ Arduino :

```
const int ledVermelho = 7;
char entrada;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(ledVermelho,OUTPUT); 
}

void loop() {
    entrada = Serial.read();
    if (entrada == 'a') {
        digitalWrite(ledVermelho,HIGH);
    }

    if (entrada == 'b') {
        digitalWrite(ledVermelho,LOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a sample of your source code that isn't working?

Comment: No, i just use winform to interact with arduino  using SerialPort class but i don't have any ideia how to do this, i just found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn264586.aspx) but doesn't help much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With https://processing.org/ and his additional library "G4P" you could create buttons easily.

After this, you could connect Arduino and Processing following this guide: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/connecting-arduino-to-processing .

At least, you could use processingJS to create the app for your windows phone (just search processing windows phone on google and you will find a lot of guide).

Or at least, you could just use the windows phone app "BT Terminal" to connect each other. But maybe, it seems to be too much unprofessional.